# Is it possible to find equivalent X/Y coordinates in order to print some text at the same position using both ^FO as well as ^FT command using ZPL 2

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

I am trying to find out if there is a possible way via which we can convert the X/Y coordinates from the `^FO` command to the equivalent `^FT` coordinates in such a way that the position of text in the label does not change.

I see that the only difference between the two commands is that position is that the text would be printed from top to bottom from the specified X/Y coordinates when we use the `^FO` command, while using `^FT` command would print it from bottom to top from the specified coordinates (see example below).

ZPL Code:

```
^XA
^CI0
^FT100,50^A0N,50,50^FDSAMPLE TEXT^FS
^FO100,50^A0N,50,50^FDSAMPLE TEXT^FS
^XZ
```

Output:

[image: ZPL Output]

Now, if I want to print the text exactly at the same position in the label then I will need to adjust the Y-coordinate value but I am not able to figure out any formula via which same can be done.

I have tried setting the Y-coordinate of `^FT` command = Y-coordinate of `^FO` command + height (which is 50 + 50 = 100 in above case) but this doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Any thoughts on the same would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I see that` - you shouldn't be guessing, this is documented. Please see page 1436 in the [ZPL manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried setting the Y-coordinate of ^FT command = Y-coordinate of ^FO command + height

This approach is correct in general, but you are adding too much. You are adding the entire height of the character cell (that is what the 50 in `^A0,50` means), while `^FT` works off the baseline of the font, and the baseline is not at the bottom of the character cell. You need to calculate yourself where it is.

As the [ZPL manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) tells you on page 1413, for the proportional font (`^A0`) the baseline height is 3 * cell height / 4. Your cell height is 50, so that gives you 37.5. This is what you should add to your `^FO` Y-coordinate.

```
^XA
^CI0
^FT100,87^A0N,50,50^FDSAMPLE TEXT^FS
^FO100,50^A0N,50,50^FDSAMPLE TEXT^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks a lot @GSerg !!

Comment: Hi @GSerg/@evilmandarine - Is there a similar equation that we could use for rotated text (for eg: whenever ^A0B (270 rotation)) is applied?
For 270 rotation, I observed that
FOy = FTy - (height * 0.25)
works perfectly fine but I am not sure about the calculation of X-coordinate value since it also depends on the length of the text/data that we print and the reference points are different as well.

Comment: @DeepPandya Please refer to page 1438 of the same manual. From the two first cells of the first column you can see that you need to add height*3/4 to X, and height*textlen to Y. For A0, the intercharacter gap is dynamic, so you cannot reliably know it. You are not supposed to be doing this in the first place, let alone automatically. You design the sizes manually in one way or another and leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

In complement to @GSerg's answer, *in this particular case* (font A0), the following formula seems to work (i.e. add 75% of the font height in dots to FT y-coord to obtain aligned FO y-coord):

`yFO = yFT + (font height in dots * .75)`

This also work for some other fonts but not all of them, so some tweaking of the scale may be required.
Here's a sample code that you can test, either with your printer or in Labelary:

```
^XA
^CI0

^FT10,50^A0N,20,20^FDFT 50^FS
^FT10,65^A0N,20,20^FDFT 65^FS
^FO70,50^A0N,20,20^FDFO 50^FS

^FT10,50^A0N,40,40^FDFT 50^FS
^FT10,80^A0N,40,40^FDFT 80^FS
^FO200,50^A0N,40,40^FDFO 50^FS

^FT10,50^A0N,50,50^FDFT 50^FS
^FT10,87^A0N,50,50^FDFT 87^FS
^FO200,50^A0N,50,50^FDFO 50^FS

^XZ
```

For better viewing keep a 3-line block only, as this shows 3 results at the same time.

Comment: Yes, you are right that calculations might change we we use a different font, but @GSerg already mentioned that the approach we could follow are already mentioned in Page 1413 (Table 26) of the [ZPL Manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf)

Comment: His answer is definitely better so I upvoted it.